# Android: NoClassDefFoundError inside email attachment

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

I'm trying to attach a picture and email it. For this, I'm using 3 jar files(mail.jar,activation-1.1.0.jar,additionnal.jar) that are copied inside libs folder and also added to BuildPath.

Following is the piece of code where error occures.

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/picture.jpg"); 
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); //error
```

Exception is:

```
09-23 11:33:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15832): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
09-23 11:33:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at com.suralal.voicerecoder.Mail.addAttachment(Mail.java:117)
```

Class definition is there in the included jar file. and import is the same.

So why 'Class definition not found' Error??

Comment: And which are the jar files that you are including? Is activation.jar among them?

Comment: @kgiannakakis: yes. I've updated question including them.

Comment: try another link to download it http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadactivation11jar.htm